# Way to return bounds of non-hidden elements in UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Right now, I have a UIScrollView which scales its UIView contents on zoom events.  When I hit a certain zoomScale threshold, I want to be able to toggle on and off extra information within the UIViews.  Right now, I am simply setting the hidden flag to YES/NO to accomplish this.

However, a problem occurs while attempting to get the bounds of the UIView.  The bounds always returns a width and height that extends to include the invisible content.

Is there a way to limit the bounds to only return the size of visible content within a UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could derive new bounds as you zoom and not rely on the view's automatic bounds adjusting.

OR

- If it doesn't make your code too complicated, I would remove those subviews from your resizing view instead of just hiding them.